# System.Composition in dotnet corefx, is it used full dotnetframework?

Tags: asp.net5

I'm upgrading from `asp.net mvc 4`, `asp.net webforms`, `Ef 5` and `MEF 1` to dotnet core.
despite existing code, that they decided to not support in dotnet core and i need to read many places to found what is going on `dotnet corefx` development, one of my big problems is that i don't understand `vs 2015's` system of adding dependency and etc.
i'm going to use `MEF2`(System.Composition), simply because it seems the `MEF1`(System.ComponentModel.Composition) is not going to be implemented in dotnet core. so i created a project of class library(package) in vs2015 as follow:
 [image]

and then typed :

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Composition
```

into PM.
now, my `project.json` file looks like this:

```
{
"version": "1.0.0-*",
"description": "___ Class Library",
"authors": [ "___" ],
"tags": [ "" ],

"frameworks": {
"net451": {
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.Composition": "1.0.30"
  }
},
"dotnet5.4": {
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
    "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
    "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
    "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
    "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
   }
  }
 }
}
```

the problem is that : is this a dnx project that only used dnx packages? and yes, the project's file extension is `.xproj`.

to me it seems that i'm using full .net framework 4.5.1 implementation of `MEF2`.
also here is a link [Using System.Composition in dotnet corefx page](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/3657) that i don't found any useful info on it.

is this means that they dont implemented the MEF2 in dotnet corefx yet?

Comment: .NET Core RC2 has released, so you should first upgrade to RC2, http://dot.net and then check the latest materials.

Answer (score 3):

Replace "dotnet5.4" for "dnxcore50". Yes, MEF 1 won't be supported, only MEF 2.
I wrote a post about using it, which you can find here: https://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/using-mef-in-net-core.